# For loop to replace word in string with name in list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, folium

I need a for loop to replace "name" in html string below with a name from name_lst.
The expected output should be the plotted map with a name at each coordinate from the lists below.

```
lat_lst = [48.6064556,52.9399159,46.510712,51.253775,53.9332706,53.7266683,53.7608608,53.1355,46.5653163,52.9399159,70.2997711,64.8255441,64.2823274]
lng_lst = [-56.3330408,-106.4508639,-63.4168136,-85.3232139,-116.5765035,-127.6476206,-98.8138763,-57.6604,-66.4619164,-73.5491361,-83.1075769,-124.8457334,-135.00000]
name_lst = ['Nova Scotia','Saskatchewan','Prince Edward Island','Ontario','Alberta','British Columbia','Manitoba','Newfoundland and Labrador','New Brunswick','Quebec','Nunavut','Northwest Terrritories','Yukon']


for lat, lng, name in zip(lat_lst, lng_lst, name_lst):
html.replace("name",name_lst,1)
folium.map.Marker(
    location=[lat,lng],
    icon=DivIcon(
    icon_size=(150,36),
    icon_anchor=(0,0),
    html='<div style="font-size: 10pt">name</div>',
    )).add_to(m)
```

Getting error : TypeError: zip argument #3 must support iteration

If anyone could help me create a Tooltip for this, it would be awesome to see the name when hovering over the coordinates.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Most likely, you replaced `name_lst` with something else before the loop

Comment: You almost surely must change `html.replace("name",name_lst,1)` to `name=html.replace("name",name,1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update, managed to solve this problem by concatenation:

```
lat_lst = [48.6064556,52.9399159,46.510712,51.253775,53.9332706,53.7266683,53.7608608,53.1355,46.5653163,52.9399159,70.2997711,64.8255441,64.2823274]
lng_lst = [-56.3330408,-106.4508639,-63.4168136,-85.3232139,-116.5765035,-127.6476206,-98.8138763,-57.6604,-66.4619164,-73.5491361,-83.1075769,-124.8457334,-135.00000]
name_lst = ['Nova Scotia','Saskatchewan','Prince Edward Island','Ontario','Alberta','British Columbia','Manitoba','Newfoundland and Labrador','New Brunswick','Quebec','Nunavut','Northwest Terrritories','Yukon']

for lat, lng, name in zip(lat_lst, lng_lst, name_lst):
    folium.map.Marker(
    location=[lat,lng],
    icon=DivIcon(
    icon_size=(150,36),
    icon_anchor=(0,0),
    html='<div style="font-size: 10pt">'+name+'</div>',
)).add_to(temp_map)
temp_map
```

Produces the correct name on the map:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check indentation for **"html.replace("name",name_lst,1)**"

I do not have problem running the for loop with zip. Please see below.

for lat, lng, name in zip(lat_lst, lng_lst, name_lst):
print(lat,lng,name)

48.6064556 -56.3330408 Nova Scotia
52.9399159 -106.4508639 Saskatchewan
46.510712 -63.4168136 Prince Edward Island
51.253775 -85.3232139 Ontario

Comment: My code is most definitely wrong, the idea is to loop through the folium.map.Marker code and replace the name in the html string with a name in name_lst as to produce the names on the map. If I leave as is it will plot the word "name" on all the coordinates in the lat, long lists on the map instead of the actual provincial name.